# how can I use another css library color rather that Material Design here?

Tags: html, css, colors

```html
<nav class="w3-sidebar w3-collapse w3-sand w3-animate-left" style="z- 
    index:3;width:300px;" id="mySidebar"><br>
  <div class="w3-container">
    <a href="#" onclick="w3_close()" class="w3-hide-large w3-right w3-jumbo 
    w3-padding w3-hover-grey" title="close menu">
      <i class="fa fa-remove"></i>
    </a>
    <img src="me.jpg" style="width:45%;" class="w3-round"><br><br>
    <h4><b>PORTFOLIO</b></h4>
    <p class="w3-text-grey">Name</p>
  </div>
  <div class="w3-bar-block">
    <a href="#portfolio" onclick="w3_close()" class="w3-bar-item w3-button 
    w3-padding w3-text-teal"><i class="fa fa-th-large fa-fw w3-margin- 
    right"></i>PORTFOLIO</a>
    <a href="#about" onclick="w3_close()" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3- 
    padding"><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw w3-margin-right"></i>ABOUT</a>
    <a href="#contact" onclick="w3_close()" class="w3-bar-item w3-button 
    w3-padding"><i class="fa fa-envelope fa-fw w3-margin-right"> . 
    </i>CONTACT</a>
  </div>
  <div class="w3-panel w3-large">
    <i class="fa fa-facebook-official w3-hover-opacity"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-instagram w3-hover-opacity"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-snapchat w3-hover-opacity"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-pinterest-p w3-hover-opacity"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-twitter w3-hover-opacity"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-linkedin w3-hover-opacity"></i>
  </div>
</nav>
```

This is a sidebar menu. I used w3-sand for the background color(nav tag, first line). The problem is, I can only use Material Design colors for my sidebar background. I can't use any other color from different css color libraries. Any idea why?

Comment: I don't see any color is there!! what are you trying to do exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Let suppose this is another css library secondlibrary.css

```
nav
{
color:red;
}
```

And this is main material design css library style for nav bar

```
nav
{
color:blue;
}
```

So if you want to use color red for nav bar rather then blue which is set by material design then there are many ways to do this. I personally recommend you to do this.

- 1: Go to another library css
- 2: Rename "nav" to ".mynav".
- 3: Use".mynav" in nav class.

  nav class="mynav w3-sidebar w3-collapse w3-sand w3-animate-left" style="z- 
  index:3;width:300px;" id="mySidebar"